# Stop Internet Explorer HTMLEncoding my URL

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

If I have this javascript:

```
var url = 'http://vv1.com/?name=a&reg=2';
location.replace(url);
```

Internet Explorer will encode the `&reg` part as a registered trademark symbol and break the URL.
Why would it do this? If it was to URLEncode it, I could understand it, but it applies HTML encoding instead.

I know that a workaround is to make `reg` the first parameter but there must come a time where this is not possible, e.g. if there is more than one parameter in danger of being encoded.

How can I stop it from happening?

Comment: You can just do this
location.replace(url.replace( '&','&amp;'));

Comment: or use `encodeURI(url)` but still I wonder why IE does behave like that

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan No you can't - you are confusing HTML encoding and URL encoding. If I use &amp; as a querystring parameter delimiter, the server won't recognise the parameter.

Comment: @Kaiido `encodeURI` will not make any difference. IE will still do the same thing.